# Node.js module inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

I'm having a problems properly defining inheritance in my app when my parent class has dependencies that I don't specify again for my child class.

Here is my setup:

**parent.js**

```
var foo = require('foo');

function Parent() {};

Parent.prototype.getFoo = function() {
    return foo;
};

module.exports = Parent;
```

**child.js**

```
var util = require('util');
var Parent = require('./parent');

function Child() {
    Parent.call(this);
}

util.inherits(Child, Parent);

module.exports = Child;
```

In my app, if I call `child.getFoo()`, it will return `undefined` unless I declare `var foo = require('foo')` in the `Child` class.

Is there a way to avoid this kind of redundancy?  I'd like to set up dependencies only once in the parent class and avoid having to copy paste code to any other classes that inherit from it.

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: This is adding a lot more work for you and for anyone else who works on this code. Most modules are designed to not be one include for the entire codebase. The `require()` function and Node's module system cache the required code, so it's not like there's added overhead.

Comment: Ok I see.  I guess I was thinking from a more OOP approach where if a parent class imports a dependency, it would transfer to any child classes

Comment: Your code should work, I can't reproduce (I replaced 'foo' by 'fs' for my test)

Comment: Thinking in OOP in JavaScript might be ok, but you can better use of it. Did you read on various design patterns on js? Just suggesting here. Also, as Volune says, there might be issue with your "foo" module, as the above code should work.